Why does photoshop treat line height as line width and vice versa?
I've created a new 50 px by 50 px wide image in Adobe PhotoShop with only one transparent layer. I've not rotated either the image or the canvas.
But when I draw a simple line 50 px high (and 3 px wide) in the center of the canvas, it shows this line to be 50 px wide, even when the width of the line is just 3 pixels. (See in the attached SS pls). If I rotate the canvas, then the reference becomes correct. But why default is referring it otherwise/wrong? Why do I have to rotate the canvas to get the terminology correct? 
Why is it referring height as width and width as height?

Have a look at the 'transform' panel on the right showing 90° rotation.

I am unable to replicate the behavior detailed here.

@Scott In PShop v2024 I just created a new file (with transparent layer) and took line tool and drew the line from top to bottom. Nothing special. And it showed the line to be at 90 degrees, because of which the confusion (mentioned in OP) arose.

After posting the question, I further explored (and read the 'Correct' comment by @Mg_ also) that my shape is showing 90 degree rotated.
But as I said in my OP, I never rotated my shape/path (whatever it is).
So the conclusion is that in PShop, whatever you draw along the x axis (horizontal axis), it is at 0 degree rotation. And if you draw along the Y-axis (perpendicular) Ps automatically thinks that the object was horizontal, but is now vertically rotated. This is a bit peculiar to me, since as Corel User, I'm accustomed to that initially whatever I draw, along whatever axis, is considered to be at zero degree rotation.
Anyway,hope I've added something new here.

for many tools in both indesign and photoshop, if you change settings in the palette without an object selected, this will set a new default for the tool. If you select the tool, ensure no object is selected and set the rotation to 0 prior to using the tool, does the behavior change?

@Yorik PS (v20, 2022, 2024) don't give any option to change 'Rotation' until we select a shape or path. Width and height can be given/set before drawing any shape/path, but not rotation. (I could attach a ss to this comment, if there was a way)
